# É possivel identificar um programador sênior por sua reputação?

Tags: debate

É possivel identificar um programador sênior por sua reputação no *stackoverflow*? Qual seria a sua reputação caso for verdade? e se não, quais os fatores que influenciam para identificar um programador sênior no *stackoverflow*?

Comment: Reputação não tem relação com vínculos profissionais de alguém, nem de idade, **nem de habilidade ou competência**.

Comment: Mas é possivel reconhecer um programador sênior pelo stackoverflow?

Comment: Se ele colocar no seu perfil que é um programador de nível sênior, você vai identificar. Alguns perfis aqui no SOpt têm vínculo com o LinkedIn (você acha isso na bio), você pode dar uma olhada em cada um, mas não serão todos que você encontrará essa informação. Na verdade, serão poucos. O StackOverflow não pede informações sobre sua carreira profissional para participar da comunidade.

Comment: Acredito que reputação possa ser um indício de senioridade, mas não necessariamente... um programador em começo de carreira pode participar bastante do SO, e com isso adquirir reputação, mas na prática pode não conseguir aplicar os conceitos de forma correta.

Comment: Tem programadores aqui no site com score elevado que realmente vivem de helpdesk, mas pecam muito em conhecimento técnico (entender como as coisas funcionam). Ainda sim eu diria que fora olhar o score, se os RHs da vida (e "headhunters") olhassem perfis aqui no site provavelmente teriam melhor qualidade, mas o mercado BR é estranho, "caçam numeros" de pessoas e não qualidade. Fico observando os RHs e HHs no linkedin, é um absurdo as estratégias de contratação deles, fora que eles ***não intermediam NADA***, provavelmente a maioria buscam numeros para empresas para ganhar "comissão", e só.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

É possível identificar mais ou menos um bom desenvolvedor por tudo o que faz no Stack Overflow e outros lugares, de forma até melhor do que um um processo de seleção que uma empresa faz, o que me faz pensar porque no Brasil as empresas não percebem isto.

Aqui explica um pouco porque departamentos de RH são péssimos para selecionar pessoas que trabalham com ofícios essencialmente técnicos e porque as contratações acabam sendo ruins em muitos desses casos.

A reputação em si só indica que a pessoa é dedicada ao SO. Claro, não é fácil obter grande reputação só falando besteira, mas a única prova que a reputação dá é de atividade intensa, o resto deve ser inferido junto com outros aspectos.

Muitas pessoas votam em algo por retribuição, por ter respondido algo que elas desejavam, nem sempre porque é bom.

Um dos problemas de se avaliar se uma pessoa é sênior sem você ser é que cai no [efeito Duning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect), ou seja, você ainda não tem o conhecimento necessário para isto, então qualquer pessoa que aparenta saber mais que você em um assunto para você será um sênior, mesmo que não seja em escala profissional. Quando você vai votar em uma resposta tende a considerar como boas algumas coisas potencialmente ruins porque você não sabe muito sobre aquilo e sua avaliação pode estar equivocada.

Como isto ocorre muito, muita gente pode ter mais reputação do que o conhecimento efetivo. Raramente alguém tem menos reputação do que deveria, porque deve acontecer alguma coisa para ter tão pouco, ou ela participa pouco, ou ela se expressa mal, ou não entende a dinâmica do site ou ela não tem o conhecimento. Então mesmo que ela seja um profissional excelente a reputação baixa ainda reflete a sua inadequação ao site.

Nem vou falar de outros *bias* emocionais que podem interferir em qualquer avaliação que as pessoas tentem fazer porque acho que começa a fugir do que interessa para nós aqui.

Só lembrando que senioridade não é título, ainda que departamentos de RH achem que seja.

Enfim, é preciso fazer uma análise minuciosa do que a pessoa responde para tentar fazer essa avaliação e para isto é preciso dominar o que se está avaliando. A reputação é só uma forma matemática de olhar com mais cuidado para alguns, mas isso dará muitos falsos negativos (a pessoa não tem reputação mas é boa no que faz) ou positivos (ganhou pontos por quantidade de atividade e avaliação condescendente de usuários que não são bons naquilo). Não confie muito nisto.

Answer (score 11):

Normalmente, pessoas com pontuação alta apresentam as seguintes características:

- Sabe colocar de forma clara seu problema
- Sabe responder de forma clara uma pergunta
- Tem conhecimento em diferentes áreas
- Escreve bem
- Gosta de compartilhar informações
- São bons desenvolvedores

Entre outras. Estas características são muito comuns em desenvolvedores considerados Sênior pela indústria.

Porém, não quer dizer que é, de fato, um Sênior.

Fatores como experiência, liderança, paciência, humildade, delegar tarefas, saber ouvir os colegas, etc, não são identificáveis olhando apenas a pontuação e são características que também costumam ser necessárias nos desenvolvedores Sênior.

Alguns destes atributos, porém, podem ser identificados olhando como o desenvolvedor interage com os outros usuários do SO nas suas respostas, comentários, aqui no meta, etc. Mas, olhando apenas a pontuação, é improvável tirar alguma conclusão destes aspectos.